# Fitting an ellipse to a point with the first and second derivatives specified

Tags: differential-geometry, conic-sections, plane-curves

I am trying to fit an ellipse to the end of a curve, $y(x)$, such that first and second derivatives of the curve, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$, are preserved at the contact point, $(x,y)$, and the ellipse has its centre on the $x$-axis.

For an ellipse of the form:
$$ \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2} = 1 $$

I have $y_0 = 0$, so that the centre is on the $x$-axis, and

$$ x_0 = x - \frac{(y-y_0)\frac{dy}{dx}}{(y-y_0)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} $$

$$ a = \pm \left((x-x_0)^2 - \frac{(x-x_0)(y-y_0)}{\frac{dy}{dx}}\right)^{1/2} $$

$$ b = \pm\frac{a(y-y_0)}{\left( a^2 - (x-x_0)^2 \right)^{1/2}}$$

where the above equations have been obtained by following the algebra through (hopefully correctly).

When I apply this to some examples (see below) I appear to get complex results (for $b$), where it looks as if there should be a real result. What is the reason for this? Does a real solution exist?

E.g. Fit ellipse to polynomial:
$$ y = \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma $$
where $\alpha = -0.14$, $\beta = 4.37$ and $\gamma = -28.8$, at $x=11.9$.

This gives $y=3.38$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=1.04$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-0.28$ at the contact point. Using the equations above the ellipse parameters come out as $x_0 = -14.72$, $a = 24.94$ and $b = -9.05i$.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating two times the equation of the ellipse leads to the quations which are solved as shown in attachment.

[image]

Comment: This is essentially how I got the above formulae. Plugging in the numbers for the example provided into your result gives the same values for $x0$, $a$ and $b$ - leading to a complex value for $b$. Does this mean that a real ellipse does not exist for the example (because, visually, it seems like one should)?

Comment: This is a consequence of the condition "the center must be on the x-axis". To be more general one should look for "a conic". The condition "an ellipse" is restrictive. In some range of $x$ the fitting conic is an ellipse. In other range it is an hyperbola. At the limit between both it is a parabola (center on x-axis at infinity). In the case of your numerical example, the range where the fitting conic is an ellipse is approximately $12.055<x<19.160$

Comment: The condition for the conic to ne an ellipse is $T_2 Y< - T_1^2$

Comment: In oder to understand why the condition "center of the conic on the x-axis", in some cases can exclude any solution (no ellipse, no hyperbola), consider for example the point (x,y=0) of the given function $y=\alpha x^2+\beta x +\gamma$ Here the tangent is not vertical, while the tangent of any conique is vertical (conic with center on x-axis). Hense, at this point, no conic can comply the stated conditions.